# new lampp but access forbidden

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

Thanks for taking the time to read this, even if seems to be a straightforward issue. To save typing this out, understand that I restart lampp after each and every attempted solution.

I have a newly extracted xampp for linux in my /opt/ directory. 
I have run /opt/lampp/lampp security.
Browsing to 'localhost' works fine. Clicking on phpmyadmin asks for my pma credentials, which when supplied presents me with the new security concept error.

At first it gave me the new security concept error message. I disabled all of those lines from /opt/lampp/etc/extras/httpd-xampp.conf.

'localhost' still works, and phpmyadmin still doesn't. But now it's giving me just the plain access forbidden, not the new security concept error.

Next I tried changing the permissions, gradually turning all of the security down until I finally tried

sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin

Still can't get phpmyadmin to work.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.